# Super expression must either be null or a function Uppy Plugin React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, uppy

Super expression must either be null or a function Uppy Plugin :
Here my My Component Code Block Check:

```
import Uppy from '@uppy/core';
import { DashboardModal, useUppy } from '@uppy/react';
import Tus from '@uppy/tus';
import React from 'react';


   const FileUploaderMulti = () => {
     const uppy = useUppy( () => {
        return new Uppy()
          .use( Tus, { endpoint: 'https://tusd.tusdemo.net/files' } );
      } );
    
      return ( <DashboardModal uppy={uppy} />
      );
    };
    
    export default FileUploaderMulti;
```